# How to get all users that have more than a certain number of messages?

Tags: mysql, dbeaver

I have a database which ER diagram looks like this:

[image]

I struggle to get all the users which have for example more than a five messages. I was able to write a query in python:

```
q = "SELECT user_id from users"
for row in cursor.execute(q):
    inner_cur = connect.cursor()
    n = inner_cur.execute("SELECT count(*) from messages WHERE user_id='{}' ".format(row[0])).fetchall()[0][0]
    # print("user_id =", row[0], "num of messages =", n)
    if n > 5:
        c = connect.cursor()
        print(c.execute("SELECT username from users WHERE user_id='{}' ".format(row[0])).fetchall()[0][0])

connect.commit()
```

But I need to do it in DBeaver. I thought that maybe I need to use `join`, `count` or `group by`, but I can't think of how. Could somebody please explain how to do it?

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT username 
FROM users JOIN messages USING (user_id)
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 5
```

I suggest picking up a book on SQL.